# Equinoctial Elements and Perturbative Effects

Tags: tracking, two-line-elements

I have an Orbital model in Equinoctial Elements [(paper)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1985CeMec..36..409W). There is a perturbative acceleration term in the model.

Can someone point me to some relevant papers showing how to include different perturbative effects like the drag, solar radiation and others?

Comment: This is extremely broad as written. Perhaps the last part by itself (how to get equinoctial elements from TLEs) would be a better title/question.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! Take [the tour](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour). "I need, I need, how can I get..." this is a tall order, and too broad to be a good stackexchange question. Can you start with something more specific and narrow? @Chris ' suggestion perhaps?

Comment: Thank you @uhoh for your feedback. I have edited the question. I hope the questions asked are clearer now.

Comment: Looks great, thanks! The link to the paper really helps as well. You might even consider adding a few eye-catching words to the title, e.g. *Filtering Algorithm on Satellite Orbit Data - Equinoctial Elements and Perturbative Effects*